# How to transform xml using jdom2 and a xslt 2.0 stylesheet

Tags: xslt-2.0, jdom-2

Does anyone know what `TransformerFactory` I should use to transform xml using jdom2 and a XSLT 2.0 stylesheet?

Comment: The commercial editions of Saxon 9 have support for JDOM, see http://saxonica.com/documentation9.5/sourcedocs/thirdparty.html. Whether that works with the JAXP API or only with Saxon's own API I am not sure.

Comment: I was hoping to find an open source solution

Comment: Please look at the page Martin has indicated: _"Support for Axiom, JDOM, JDOM2, XOM, and DOM4J is not available "out of the box" with Saxon-HE, but the source code is open source (in sub-packages of net.sf.saxon.option) and can be compiled for use with Saxon-HE if required"_.